# Reason for high response time of a transaction during Load test

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, response-time

I am doing load testing for one hour and observed one transaction is taking high response time compared to expected value. Why is this happening? What could be the reasons even if GC, thread and system resources (CPU and Memory) utilization are normal.

How to analyze it?

Answer (score 0):

Numerous. The most obvious ones would be:

- Slow database query - use a [DB Monitoring Tool](https://www.eginnovations.com/product/database-monitoring) to see what happens on database level
- An issue with your application code (memory leak, large object, "heavy" function) - re-run your test with [Profiler Tool](http://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) telemetry and collect all the information on JVM heap, threads, objects, etc. as you can. A [thread dump](https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps) can shed light on where your application is stuck
- It can be even a networking issue, response time includes metrics like [Connect Time](https://varvy.com/performance/tcp-connection-time.html) and [Latency](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0) (time to first byte) so you can receive higher response times due to low network capacity or even a faulty router

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T Thank You